# How to use checkbox in apex5 and when checked it update table

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I'm new to apex and have a region (interactive report) tht contains students details One of the field is date_of_entry I would like to add a checkbox for this field and when user check it. Then tht specific row get automatically updated in table with current sysdate.
How to do that add wz examples pls

Answer (score 0):

Interactive Reports are not editable in versions < 5.1. So, you will need to add an editable column using APEX_ITEM function to display checkbox item on every row.

```
SELECT A.COURSE_ID,
  A.COURSE_NAME,
  B.PAYMENT_DATE,
  B.RECEIVEDBY_EMPL,
  APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(1,A.COURSE_ID) "Select"
FROM COURSE_INFO A,
  PAYMENT_INFO B
WHERE A.COURSE_ID = B.COURSE_ID
AND A.STUDENT_ID  = :P2_ID;
```

[Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#CHDDCHAF) for more info on this function.

Now processing part, all APEX items are posted on form submit regardless of whether user has checked them or not. Loop through all items and update table where value is not null.

```
DECLARE
  L_COURSE_ID WWV_FLOW_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
BEGIN
  L_COURSE_ID := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01;
  FOR IDX IN 1 .. L_COURSE_ID.COUNT
  LOOP
    IF L_COURSE_ID(IDX) IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE PAYMENT_INFO
      SET PAYMENT_DATE=SYSDATE
      WHERE COURSE_ID =L_COURSE_ID(IDX)
      AND STUDENT_ID  =:P2_ID;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: thks kapiell, i've managed to add the checkbox for the field.  How to add the on-form submit process .. should a button be created or via dynamic action ?

Comment: is it possible for u to help? i got workspace online on apex.oracle.com.. im not able to implement the on-form submit.. :( ur help wl be highly appreciated

Comment: Sure, what's your workspace name, user name and password?

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4000:4500:12442352516601::NO:::

workspace: AKIKA
AKIKA1508@GMAIL.COM 
password01

Comment: updated answer to reflect actual table names. test instance is also working, i changed checkbox value from date to course id and added update process.

Comment: Kapiell, is it possible to get ur email add for queries on apex5?

Comment: I have replied to akika1508@gmail.com